# ANE - FREContext activity status changes notifications (onStart, onResume, etc)

Tags: android-activity, air, air-native-extension

Im dealing with this problem and I cannot find a solution yet.
Basically I need to receive a notification/event/whatever when activity status is changing. I don't have a way to override onStart, onResume and those activity methods. So is there any way to do it when you are building ANEs?

Im using Android API 9, I see there's a possible solution for the API 14+ using the Application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks() (I didn't try that yet), but that's not possible for API 9.

On the AS3 side I can listen those event, so a possible solution is to notify to JAVA from AS3 (that sound so painful, more considering that I don't need those methods for iOS)
Thanks for any help,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Air can receive only events of type "StatusEvent" from a native extension, which must be dispatched from your extension.

There are some helper function defined in the "FRE" package, which will do the job on the native side, as "public void dispatchStatusEventAsync( String code, String level )" for the java part.

The usage can be found [here in the docs.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WS39e706a46ad531be-fd70de2132a8f3874e-8000.html)

Comment: that method is for sending custom events from Java to AS3, I don't see more details in the documentation related to the Activity events. Regarding my last comment in this post, I was saying to oposite, to hear the events that I need on AS3 (onStart, onResume, etc) if possible, and send them to Java, as a (bad) way to resolve my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem. Don't know about the Java side. To implement your workaround, you simply could call a custom method, passing the (flash-side) event-string as argument to handle it in Java.